# find does not succeed to exclude a specific directory

Tags: find

I want to list all the files except those inside `.git/` directory with the `find` command only.

I tried this:

```bash
$ find . -path .git -prune -type f
$
```

it returned 0 files (instead of the 2 I have) so I tried this :

```bash
$  find . -not -path .git -type f | grep -c '\.git'
1770
$
```

I don't understand why none of these is working, can you help ?

EDIT0 : Thanks to @icarus, I see that the paths must be preceded by `./` and that I was missing the `OR` operator consequently, this command works :

```bash
$ find . -path ./.git -prune -o -type f | grep '\.git'
./.git
./.gitignore
$
```

EDIT1 : Why does that other command does not work ?

```bash
$ find . -not -path ./.git -a -type f | grep -c '\.git'
1770
$
```

EDIT2 : One last question : why does the `-prune` predicate need a `-o -print` not to print the `./.git` and `./.gitignore` results in the command below :

```bash
$ find . -name ".git*" -prune | grep git
./.git
./.gitignore
$ find . -name ".git*" -prune -o -print | grep -c git
0
```

EDIT3 : Thank you @rastafile :

```bash
$ find . -name ".git*" -prune | grep git
./.git
./.gitignore
$ find . -name ".git*" -prune -print | grep git
./.git
./.gitignore
$ find . -name ".git*" -prune -o -print | grep git
$
```

It seems the GNU find `-prune` predicate calls `-print` implicitly when the previous expression is true :

> If  the  expression  contains  no  actions  other  than -prune, -print
>   is performed on all files for which the expression is true.

In conclusion : The command I need is :

```bash
$ find . -name ".git*" -prune -o -type f -print
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: short answer to EDIT2: one '-print' is added by `find` if there is none, even for '-prune'. So you have to steal the builtin '-print' it from '-prune'.

Comment: @rastafile Thanks a lot. Now I understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between `-path` and `-name` -- they are not at all similar: "name" only looks at the last part, "path" at the whole chain of slashes. What a "filename" should mean, or a "pathname", is always a bit controversial. But here it is clear and important.

This works (you say):

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -o -type f
```

You start from `.`, so the default gitdir gets found and pruned. No other `./.git` exists, so everybody else (`-o`) is checked for type file.

---

Your last example:

```
find . -not -path ./.git -a -type f
```

does not work, it just finds all *files*.

If you want to avoid `-prune`, you have to match **each** entry inside:

```
-path './.git/*'
```

---

I agree with Icarus' -name/-prune combination, but I have a modification:

```
]# find . -name .git -prune -o -type f -name '*git*' -print   
./.git.filehidd
./gitfile
```

The parens are not needed, here.

Even if `-name '*git*'` is added, for testing/reducing output.

The explicit action `-print` at the end suppresses a print by prune:

```
]# find . -name .git -prune                                 
./.git
./10/.git
```

---

I was unsure about the parens; I looked up `man find` (GNU) and found this nice detail about them:

```
 find . -name .snapshot -prune -o \( \! -name *~ -print0 \)
```

> ..., but
>   omits files and directories named .snapshot (and anything in them).
>          It also omits files or directories whose name ends in ~, but not their contents.  **The construct `-prune -o \( ...  -print0  \)`  is 
>   quite
>          common.**  The  idea  here is that the expression before -prune matches things which are to be pruned.  However, the -prune action
>   itself
>          returns true, so the following -o ensures that the right hand side is evaluated only for those directories which didn't get pruned 
>   (the
>          contents  of  the  pruned directories are not even visited, so their contents are irrelevant).  The expression on the right hand side
>   of
>          the -o is in **parentheses only for clarity**.  It emphasises that the -print0 action takes place only for things that  didn't  have 
>   -prune
>          applied  to  them.   Because  the  default `and' condition between tests binds **more tightly than -o**, this is the default anyway,
>   but the
>          parentheses help to show what is going on.

To me the clarity would be enhanced by rather:

```
find . ( -name .snapshot -prune ) -o ( ! -name '*~' -print0 )
```

But like that it does not work!

And if you leave out the `-a` like here, the `-o` stands out enough, so the parens can be left out, also for clarity.

---

(Because the shell likes parens too, **you have to quote them**. But then goodbye to clarity.)

```
1) find . -name .snapshot -prune -o \( \! -name *~ -print0 \)

2) find . -name .snapshot -prune -o ! -name '*~' -print0
```

The unquoted `!` can work (mine does), the unquoted `*` not.

---

So to find files (all kinds) except in any dir `.git`:

```
find -name '.git' -type d -prune -o -print
```

(the type -d can also be left out, if you don't care...see Kamil's *comment*...it's a jungle out *there*, and find is a small *programming language*: what you need)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Do you have an answer to my last question in my EDIT2 ?

Comment: @Paulo Tomé I don't agree with the quoting of the parenthses - from find's point of view they are unquoted, for clarity. I only add them for the shell.  Man find: **( expr )**
              Force precedence.  Since parentheses are special to the shell, you will **normally** need to quote them.

Comment: @rastafile Reverted the modification.

Comment: @Paulo Tomé thanks! I will add a remark about that - "clarity enhanced -- functionality zero"

Comment: @rastafile I simply want to suggest you to remove the `find .` before the `find` expression that contains unquoted parenthesis to let people know it's not a shell command (that one can copy and paste) but a `find` expression.

Comment: @rastafile Nope. Forget about my `('` and `')'` quoting comment. I have deleted it because it was kinda stupid.

Comment: @rastafile I would rather have you remove the `find .` before your `find` expression that contains unquoted parenthesis to avoid the confusion with a shell command. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no confusion at all! The DOT is not a _special argument_ like STAR is, and is not a _control operator_ like (parens) are. It is in second place, so it is not a command, here.

Comment: @rastafile OK. Let's hope that in the future nobody, thinking it's a shell command, copies and pastes your unquoted parenthesis expression to adapt it to their own will : `find . ( -name .snapshot -prune ) -o ( ! -name '*~' -print0 )`

Comment: why does -path ./.git  work but -path .git doesn't?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The default operation to join terms in find is `and` so

```
find / -user root -name fred
```

means to find files which are both belonging to root and called fred. You want to do an `or` operation, if it it called ".git" then prune it or if it is a file then list it.

```
find . \( -name .git -prune \) -o -type f
```

Note I am using `-name` rather than `-path`. If you give it a starting location of `.` then the `.git` directory in the top level will be called `./.git` for the purposes of `-path`.

So

```
find . -path .git -prune -type f
```

gives nothing because nothing matches `-path .git` as all files start `./`

```
find . -not -path .git -type f
```

gives you every file because everything matches `-not -path .git` so the only filtering is `-type f` to restrict the output to files.

Comment: The explanation is right, the command can be improved. With `find . \( -name .git -prune \) -o -type f` there's a quirk: it will print every file (of any type, i.e. also every directory) named `.git`. Improvement: `find . \( -type d -name .git -prune \) -o -type f -print`. This prunes every `.git` directory (possibly somewhere deeper within `.`) without printing its path. If we omit `-type d` then it won't print a non-directory named `.git` (if any) somewhere in a non-excluded directory; so `-type d` is desired when excluding directories this way.

Comment: @icarus Thanks a lot for your answer. Can you please now read my EDIT0 and my EDIT1 ?

Comment: I have read EDIT0. I think this is addressed by @KamilMaciorowski comment. EDIT1 just puts in the `-a` explicitly - I am not clear what is being asked.

Comment: @icarus I want to list all the files except those inside `.git/` directory with the `find` command only. I'd like to understand why the last command does not work : `find . -not -path ./.git -a -type f`

Comment: if you're finding in a path with many repos, youll additionally want to exclude .git directories from the output: `find . \( -type d -name .git -prune -not -name .git \) -o -type f`